# vmWare Snapshot removal using script

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I was trying to remove snapshots which are older than particular days, I don't want remove them if their description is marked with `PERM`.

Also if the description is marked with `DELT` delete them on a particular date.

It all works well if the VM has only one snapshot, but with multiple it fails to check for the second snapshot and remove them.

```
$AllSnaps = Get-VM  | Get-Snapshot | select VM, Name, Description, sizemb, Created

ForEach ($Snap in $AllSnaps) {
    $Identity = $null
    $DelDate = $null
    Try {
        $Identity = $Snap.Description.Substring(0, 4)
        $DelDate = $Snap.Description.Substring(5)
    }
    Catch {
        $Identity = $null
        $DelDate = $null
    }

    If ($Identity -eq "DELT" -and $DelDate -ge (Get-Date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")) {
        write-host "$($snap.VM) - $($snap.Name) - $($snap.Created) -Delete Snaps (Exception Completed)" -fore "blue"    
    }
    ElseIf ($Identity -eq "PERM") {
        Write-host -"VMName : $($snap.VM) - SnapName : $($snap.Name) - Created $($snap.Created) - Size $($Snap.sizemb) - Action : Skipping - Reason :Permanent Snapshot" 
    }
    ElseIf ($Snap.created -le ($OldDate).ToShortDateString()) {
        write-host "$($snap.VM) - $($snap.Name) - $($snap.Created) - Deleting Snaps Older than 15 Days" -fore "red" 
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is probably in your command to delete rather than this logic.
Did you intend to finsih on an "ElseIf"?
And you do know it's seriously not a good idea to keep VMware snapshots permanently?

Comment: I meant to do it in the way if both the conditions are not satisfying go ahead and do some action on it. It works perfectly  to the VM's which have only one snapshot. If there are more than one the first one detects properly but not the other one.

Comment: where's the remove-snapshot command? Without that, don't know unless you are saying the if statements aren't working. Perhaps you are trying to remove a snapshot when one is being removed already, check recent events on the VM.